# Puppet Ochestration: get results of puppet run

Tags: puppet, puppet-agent, operations-orchestration, puppet-foreman

How can i get results of  `puppet apply -t --noop` in some script readable way? Are there any resources to apply? I suppose there should be something better then GREP :)

Making some modification to the underling puppet infrastructure and i would like to make sure that applications are not affected.

Scenario of orchestration:

1. stop puppet agent
2. do my stuff
3. run `puppet agent -t --noop`
4. if (3) applied resurces => rollback!
5. start puppet agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml` provides all i needed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `--detailed-exitcodes` option:

> Provide transaction information via exit codes. If this is enabled, an exit code of '2' means there were changes, an exit code of '4' means there were failures during the transaction, and an exit code of '6' means there were both changes and failures.

Comment: Unfortunatly with --noop the result is allways '0'

Comment: Score another one for Puppet's complete lack of common sense.  Sigh.